# The meaning of $ I -2vv^\top $ transformation

Tags: projection

I have a linear transformation $ A = I - 2vv^\top $ where $ v $ is n dimensional unit vector. I'm looking for a geometrical meaning for the transformation A. I can write $ A $ as $ A = (I - vv^\top ) - vv^\top $ so it is a projection onto  the nullspace of $v$ minus the projection onto  $v$. Any other geometrical insight I can gain for this transformation ?

Thanks!

Comment: If I remember it right, it has something to do with the reflection w.r.t. the subspace that is orthogonal to $v$.

Comment: $A$ has $n-1$ eigenvalues $1$ and  one eigenvalue $1-2\|v\|,$ the latter with eigenvectors $v.$ So $A$ fixes the space of vectors perpendicular to $v,$ and stretches in the direction $v.$

Comment: Try applying it to a vector $x = a v + w$, where $w$ is perpendicular to $v$. Does that help you see what it's doing?

Comment: since $v^{\top}v=1$ then $Av=Iv-2v=-v$

Comment: These are known [Householder matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation#Householder_matrix). Geometrically, they correspond to reflection. I recently gave an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190306/proof-for-the-householder-matrix/4190388#4190388) on the subject.

Comment: I think I get it - it is reflection over $  Null(vv^\top) $ in the direction of $v$.  I defined a generic vector $ m = v_k + v_c $ where $ v_k $  is coming from the kernel and $ v_c $  from the column space of  $  (vv^\top) $ and  I get $ Am= A(v_k + v_c) = v_k - v_c $